# Get data file from microphone in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I use the sample code of microphone from MSDN website. But I did not find the music file I recorded in my emulator. And can any one tell me how to find my recorded file and export it to the hard drive on laptop? Thank you!

I also write code to record the data from recording:

```
stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
using (var textFile = store.OpenFile("AudioFile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(textFile))
{ writer.Write(stream); }`
```

I do not know how to get my text file either.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940102/how-can-i-get-data-off-of-my-windows-phone-7-emulator

Comment: I'd recommend this as a duplicate as it has an up-to-date answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833918/isolated-storage-location-for-windows-phone-7/6640098#6640098

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833918/isolated-storage-location-for-windows-phone-7/6640098#6640098). In short, you need to use the ISE (Isolated Storage Explorer) command line tool that ships with the Mango SDK.