# Getting a wav file from Windows Phone microphone

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, format, wav, microphone

*This question is **not** a duplicate of [Get data file from microphone in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718566/get-data-file-from-microphone-in-windows-phone-7) or any other referenced in it.*

In Windows Phone, I record the microphone data in a following manner:

1. I start a Dispatcher.Update timer to simulate an XNA game loop.
2. I subscribe to Microphone.BufferReady and set a buffer duration. Then, I start the microphone.

   ```
   // Event handler for getting audio data when the buffer is full
   _microphone.BufferReady += MicrophoneBufferReady;

   // Get audio data in 1/2 second chunks
   _microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
   ```
3. Then, each time I get a chunk of audio data from a mic, I record it to a data stream.

   ```
   // Retrieve audio data
   _microphone.GetData(_buffer);

   _stream.Write(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length);
   ```
4. Whenever the recording is over, the data stream is saved to an Isolated Storage as a file.

   ```
   var soundFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".wav";
   using (var isStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
   {
       using (var isfStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(soundFileName, FileMode.Create, isStore))
       {
           isfStream.Write(data.ToArray(), 0, data.ToArray().Length);
           isfStream.Close();
       }
   }
   ```

   Where `data` is a `MemoryStream` holding all the microphone buffers, that were collected during the recording.

The problem is, that the file actually saved isn't a wav file. If I copy it to a desktop using an ISETool, I can't play the sound.

How do I save the microphone recording to a file, so that it is saved in a .wav format?

P.S. I can play it on the device just fine if I read the data from IS and pack it into a SoundEffect instance.

```
_soundInstance = new SoundEffect(_data, Microphone.Default.SampleRate, AudioChannels.Mono).CreateInstance();
```

Comment: here you can find code how to save the raw PCM data as WAV file: http://damianblog.com/2011/02/07/storing-wp7-recorded-audio-as-wav-format-streams/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the buffer is raw PCM.
Adding the WAV header to the start of the file is al that is required.
However the file is uncompressed and a better solution would be to zip the file on the device(to reduce its size) and send in to a web service for conversion to a compressed WAV format